# Server Client with UI, Label on UI not updating with method

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So I am trying to do a Client-Server-Project with a UI. The server has a countdown and sends every now and then a "Wake up" to the client (Dead Mens Switch). I already have the UI set up with buttons working etc.

Problem is, that I can't get to show on the UI when the WakeUp signal is send.

What my code does is that if the received message equals "Wake Up" it calls a wakeUp()-Method in the Interface.

Things I tried:

```
void wakeUp(){
        wakeUpLabel.setText("Wake up!");
    }
```

I figured I needed some sort of action listener so I created an invisible button with an action listener and did a (virtual) click on the button when the method is called:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            wakeUpLabel.setText("Wake up!");
        }
    });

void wakeUp(){
            System.out.println("wakeUpMethod");
            button1.doClick();
        }
```

The thing I don't understand is: If I put a System.out.println("ActionPerformed") in the ActionPerformed I get the output in the console but the label does not change. If I click myself on the button, the label is updating properly.

How do I update the label without klicking anything?

Comment: can you post the minimal example reproducible, for test your use case?

Comment: I used the form-tool implemented in IntelliJ. To give you a simplified version of my code I had to do the form "by hand". While testing the code it suddenly worked. So it seems like it was a problem with IntelliJ-Form-Maker. I will write the UI by hand now. Thanks!

Comment: [mre] is a powerful debugging tool

Comment: it is, indeed..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no reason to trigger a click on a fake button do update a GUI, it just make some useless heavy code to be runned in addition to your method.

In place of it, just use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to call the update statement in a runnable block... try something like this:

```
void wakeUp(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            wakeUpLabel.setText("Wake up!");
        }
    });
}
```

When calling the wakeUp method, this should do the trick if the label is initialized and visible.

If this is not working you can try adding `wakeUpLabel.revalidate()` and/or `wakeUpLabel.repaint()` inside the runnable.

If you still have trouble, put a more complete example here to help reproducing the problem ;)